# Controlar que un usuario vea solo el documento que el ha generado ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iis

Tengo una pagina web con IIS y Asp.net donde los usuarios entran segun su nombre de usuario y password.
El control lo hago usando en Global.asax el metodo Session_Start() y variables Session[]

En un punto de la pagina los usuarios pueden ver un documento que esta en una carpeta de la web y mostrarlo con el comando javascript window.open(urlDeLaCarpetaWebQueEstaEnElServidor) para luego descargarse.

El problema es que de esta manera el usuario al ver la url puede probar con otro nombre de documento y puede ver algun documento de otro usuario que haya generado en esa misma carpeta.

Hay alguna manera de conseguir que cada usuario vea solo el documento que el haya generado en el servidor?

Comment: Crea un script para descarga de archivos donde recibas como parámetro el nombre de archivo; verifica que pertenece al usuario y realiza la descarga ahí mismo. Tal vez te sirva [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5830215/2412893) (en inglés).

Comment: @Triby ok.. es una manera..